# Override NSManagedObject save

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I would like to be able to execute a custom save change on an NSManagedObject whenever `[managedObjectContext save:nil]` is called.

```
self.colorRaw = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.color];
```

save to be made in this implementation. Any idea?

```
@interface Filter : NSManagedObject
//auto-generated accessor
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * colorRaw;
// custom accessor
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor * color;

@end

@implementation
- (UIColor *)color
{
    UIColor * color;
    if ((color = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(color)))) {
        return color;
    }
    if (self.colorRaw.length) {
        color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.colorRaw];
        self.color = color;
        return color;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color
{
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(color), color, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
} 
@end
```

Comment: Declare a property of type NSManagedObject lets say  *managedContext in your above code and initialize it by using AppDelegate *delegateMain= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]  now access your app delegate here   managedContext=delegateMain.managedObjectContext and now you can use this  to save you data an everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually quite easy. Simply add an observer for the key `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`

as per the doc

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(<#Selector name#>)
                                      name: NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification
                                      object:<#A managed object context#>];
```